# Appending Time at the end of csv file through cmd file

Tags: windows, csv, time, batch-file, cmd

I have a command file that already appends the current date to the end of a csv file everytime the batch job is run.  I also want to add the current time but I'm having difficulty with this.

```
   This is my code for appending the date in my cmd file:
   --------
   set yyyy=%date:~10,4%
   set mm=%date:~4,2%
   set dd=%date:~7,2%
   Report_%dd%_%mm%_%yyyy%.csv
   --------
   Result:
   Report_02_07_2013.csv
   --------
   Required Result:
   Report_02_07_2013_05_25_PM.csv
```

Can anyone show me what to add to my cmd file to get the time at the end of the code as well?  I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Change `Report_%dd%_%mm%_%yyyy%.csv` to `Report_%dd%_%mm%_%yyyy%_%TIME::=_%.csv`, or, if `%TIME%` includes fractions of seconds, something like this:

```
set ftime=%TIME:~0,8%
Report_%dd%_%mm%_%yyyy%_%ftime::=_%.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
   set "mytime=%time::=_%"
```

.. and now work with `%mytime%`, not `%time%`

Answer (score 1):

This is a robust method to get a date and time in variables.  Modify the order to suit you.  XP Pro and above.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set stamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%
echo stamp: "%stamp%"
```